# Styling for React-Table component

Tags: css, reactjs, react-table, tailwind-css

I'm trying to style a component properly. At the moment, the table works beautifully, but the style of it isn't ideal, and usually this would be easy to fix with tailwind but the components layout makes it very confusing to know exactly how to style it.

This is the example I am referencing,

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/kitchen-sink

Now specifically what I want to change is the group functions. Currently the use emoji's to work, I really want to to be a proper button so users understand very clearly the functionality of the component, as below.

```
<table className="w-full text-md bg-white shadow-md rounded mb-4" {...getTableProps()}>
          <thead>
            {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
              <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                  <th className={td_header} {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                    <div>
                      {column.canGroupBy ? (
                        // If the column can be grouped, let's add a toggle
                        <span {...column.getGroupByToggleProps()}>
                          {column.isGrouped ? 'Click to Un-Group  Click to Sort!' : ' Click to Group  Click to Sort!'}
                        </span>
                      ) : null}
                      <span {...column.getSortByToggleProps()}>
                        {column.render('Header')}
                        {/* Add a sort direction indicator */}
                        {column.isSorted
                          ? column.isSortedDesc
                            ? ' '
                            : ' '
                          : ''}
                      </span>
                    </div>
                    {/* Render the columns filter UI */}
                    <div>{column.canFilter ? column.render('Filter') : null}</div>
                  </th>
                ))}
```

Now ideally I want something like this for the group and filter toggle, taken from tailwind 
https://tailwindcss.com/components/buttons

```
<div class="inline-flex">
  <button class="bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-l">
    Group
  </button>
  <button class="bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 text-gray-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-r">
    Filter
  </button>
</div>
```

How does one go about styling this effectively, given the string it is using is not a component and does not have any styling that I can see involved?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string present in your question is not a component, but it easily could be. Those elements don't necessarily need to be strings; react-table is a headless library, so you're free to change the visuals the way you want. There are a variety of possible solutions here. One solution would be to replace the entire ternary by defining a custom functional component for that sort icon:

```js
const sortIcon = (sorted, sortedDesc) => {
  if (sortedDesc) {
    return (<h1> this is arbitrary </h1>);
  } else if (sorted) {
    return (<h2> more arbitrary </h2>);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

and then replacing the ternary:

```
<span {...column.getSortByToggleProps()}>
                        {column.render('Header')}
                        {/* Add a sort direction indicator */}
                        {sortIcon(column.isSorted, column.isSortedDesc)}
                      </span>
```

This is a bad way to do it, probably, and untested beside that, but the point is that the HTML/JSX stuff is arbitrary. Those emoji strings can be replaced with valid JSX in any form. You could do a similar thing with the `column.isGrouped` ternary, as well! It may be worth looking at some [JSX tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_jsx.htm) if you're not already familiar, or re-familiarizing yourself with [exactly what a column Object contains](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#column-options) if you want to continue to add functionality.

(link caveat: each of the different `useX` hooks adds more stuff to the `column`/`row`/etc Objects, so I just linked the core `useTable` one)